# Having trouble with jQuery toggle function for dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, toggle

I have a dropdown menu that slides up and down when toggled to reveal it's menu items. The problem is that when i go to click one of the menu items after the menu has slid down, it is recognized as a toggle and the menu slides up without opening the link of the menu item.

HTML

```
<li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#">Carbohydrates, proteins &amp; fats</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="carbohydrates.php">Carbohydrates</a></li>
                <li><a href="proteins.php">Proteins</a></li>
                <li><a href="fats.php">Fats</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
```

dropdown script:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.dropdown').toggle(
        function () {
            //show its submenu
            $('ul', this).slideDown(300);
        },
        function () {
            //hide its submenu
            $('ul', this).slideUp(300);        
        }
    );

});
```

I'd appreciate any help with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately none of the above answers were working for me. I found a solution shortly afterwards.

HTML

```
<li class="dropdown">
            <a class="disablelink" href="#">Carbohydrates, proteins &amp; fats</a>
            <ul class="sub_navigation">
                <li><a href="carbohydrates.php">Carbohydrates</a></li>
                <li><a href="proteins.php">Proteins</a></li>
                <li><a href="fats.php">Fats</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
```

jquery script

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('.dropdown').click(function() {
                        // When the event is triggered, grab the current element 'this' and
                        // find it's children '.sub_navigation' and display/hide them
            $(this).find('.sub_navigation').slideToggle(); 
        });

        $(".disablelink").click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
        });

    });
```

That solution is working perfectly for me. I added in `e.preventDefault();` to stop the page jumping up and down when i clicked on the link.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you individually closing/opening the menu items?  Everything gets hidden anyway when the parent `<li>` element is hidden -- why do anything after that?

I think you want to [disable event bubbling](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/).

---

EDIT 1: You're over-complicating things. Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.dropdown').toggle();
});
```

---

EDIT 2: Can you be more specific about what you want? If you want a particular element, when clicked, to control the motion of a particular list, try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('a.someLink').click(function() {
       $('.dropdown').toggle();
    });
});
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean? I'm individually closing/opening the menu items because that's what i'm trying to do. I don't know what you're referring to when you say, "why do anything after that"?

Comment: I tried that code but it just seems to hide my list item - the one with `class="dropdown"`.

Comment: When you click a link (or another element), do you want that to fire the dropdown/up motion?

Comment: Sorry, i probably wasn't specific enough. If you take my example above, when i click `<a href="#">Carbohydrates, proteins &amp; fats</a>` i want the dropdown list to appear. When i click on one of `carbs`, `proteins`, or `fats` links that will open their respective link. I can also toggle the dropdown menu closed again by clicking `<a href="#">Carbohydrates, proteins &amp; fats</a>`. That's the behaviour i'm looking for

Comment: Give that link a custom CSS class, and use that CSS class as a jQuery selector (using my above code).

Answer (score 0):

Try moving the triggering link outside of the dropdown items

```
<a href="#" class="dropdown">Carbohydrates, proteins &amp; fats</a>
<div class="divdropdown">
   <ul>
       <li><a href="carbohydrates.php">Carbohydrates</a></li>
       <li><a href="proteins.php">Proteins</a></li>
       <li><a href="fats.php">Fats</a></li>
   </ul>
</div>​
```

And then slightly modify your jquery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.dropdown').toggle(
        function () {
            //show its submenu
            $('ul', $(".divdropdown")).slideDown(300);
        },
        function () {
            //hide its submenu
            $('ul', $(".divdropdown")).slideUp(300);        
        }
    );
});​
```